# Error while running php project using netbeans

Tags: php, ubuntu, netbeans, browser, xampp

I'm getting an error while running my project. This is the error that i'm getting:

[image: Error message]

By the way my IDE is Netbeans and the webserver is XAMPP.
I already created a java/html5 project, its running well but not when it's a PHP file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    // put your code here
    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message tells you that the URL not found. So I am sure that `PhpProject1/index.php` is not right path in your localhost. For making sure please open the path folder of `xampp/htdocs/[PhpProject1/index.php must be here]`. Hope it will help you.

Comment: you mean, when i creating new PHP project, its must be located on opt/lampp/xampp/htdocs?
it cant be located on other location?

Comment: thats right, you must create project inside htdocs folder. Make sure you write URL of your right folder. Because the right folder and netbeans project name it can be different

Comment: Why do you place folder xampp inside lampp folder? Is that right?

Comment: i just do default installation i think its same like using windows OS, but its different

Comment: Yes because you use linux, dont you?

Answer (score 0):

[location problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0pE0.png)
it cant be changed...

it not writeable
[location problem2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHDwM.png)